# Can I throw a warning when an invalid (by my rules) value is assigned to a member of an object?

Tags: javascript

Chromium (V8?) threw a warning when I assigned the wrong value to a member of a built in object:

[image]

This has got to be the most unexpectedly helpful and clear warning that I have ever seen. Compare that to, say, the invariant violation warnings in React that have no context or meaningful line number. Or, to my own `console.warn` calls that happen in validation functions far away from where the user of the module actually messed up.

Is there a way that a class of my own could throw an error / warning when an invalid value is assigned to a member, that will be shown right next to the assignment, like in the picture?

Comment: You can implement a custom [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) method for your class and check against the list of possible values.

Comment: Ack, so that's what those are for. I thought they were only useful for evil magic, like entangling variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can define your properties with *accessor methods*:

```
var obj = {
    get foo() {
        return this._foo;
    },
    set foo(value) {
        if (/*...value is invalid...*/) {
            throw new Error(/*...*/);
        }
        this._foo = value;
    }
};
```

When used, they look just like normal properties:

```
obj.foo = "some value";
var x = obj.foo;
```

More here: [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Of course, with the above, a determined person could just assign to `obj._foo` instead. If you're concerned about that, you can define the accessors within an IIFE and use a local variable for the backing value:

```
var obj = (function() {
    var foo;

    return {
        get foo() {
            return foo;
        },
        set foo(value) {
            if (/*...value is invalid...*/) {
                throw new Error(/*...*/);
            }
            foo = value;
        }
    };
})();
```

That accessor method syntax is just one way to define accessors; you can also do it on an existing object via `Object.defineProperty` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.defineproperty) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)) and `Object.defineProperties` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.defineproperties) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)) (or while creating a new object with `Object.create` [[spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.create) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)] by specifying the second argument).

`defineProperty` example:

```
var obj = {};
(function() {
    var foo;

    Object.defineProperty(obj, "foo", {
        get: function() {
            return foo;
        },
        set: function(value) {
            if (/*...value is invalid...*/) {
                throw new Error(/*...*/);
            }
            foo = value;
        }
    });
})();
```

In ES2015, you can also do this when using `class`; it looks a lot like initializer syntax, but without commas between the methods:

```
class Thingy {
    get foo() {
        return this._foo;
    }
    set foo(value) {
        if (/*...value is invalid...*/) {
            throw new Error(/*...*/);
        }
        this._foo = value;
    }
}
```

To avoid the `obj._foo` problem, you could use a `WeakMap` ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-weakmap-objects) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)) to store the values keyed by `this`:

```
let Thingy = (() => {
    let foos = new WeakMap();

    class Thingy {
        get foo() {
            return foos.get(this);
        }
        set foo(value) {
            if (/*...value is invalid...*/) {
                throw new Error(/*...*/);
            }
            foos.set(this, value);
        }
    }
})();
```

There I've used a `foo`-specific map, but you could also use a map keyed by `this` to store *all* your backing properties as an object.